# Insufficient Parameters error when inserting into database, but the only field I haven't included is the auto-increment field. Must I include it? How?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm using a SQLite Database for my project, and when the code for this button runs, it says:

> System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: 'unknown error
>   Insufficient parameters supplied to the command'

Here's the code that's causing the exception:

```
SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=C:\SQLiteDB\SQLiteDB.db;Version=3;");
SQLiteCommand cmd;

  cnn.Open();
  cmd = new SQLiteCommand(@"INSERT INTO SmashRoster (CharacterName,TotalTournaments,Wins,Losses,Championships,InjuriesCaused,Injured)
                            VALUES (@name,@TournPart,@Wins,@Losses,@Champ,@InjuriesC,@Injured)",cnn);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtCharacterName.Text);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TournPart", nudTotalTourn.Value);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Wins", nudWins.Value);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Losses", nudLosses.Value);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Champ", nudChampionships.Value);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InjuruesC", nudInjuriesCaused.Value);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Injured", nudInjured.Value);
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

  cnn.Dispose();
  cmd.Dispose();
```

The only column in the table not being represented here is the primary key auto increment field.  I figured the column would automatically populate, but I'm new to SQLite and that may not be the case. (nud = numberUpDown, not sure what the proper abbreviation would be, such as btn for button) Thank you!

Comment: I suggest to check if there is a space between `Injured)` and `VALUES`

Comment: Is your code copied verbatim?  Your `new SQLiteCommand` takes a `InjuriesC`, but the `AddWithValue` call takes a `@InjuruesC`

Comment: Thank you mcalex, this was my issue! It all works now.